# Two definitions of the first Chern class

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, connections

there are two definitions of the first Chern class that I don't know how to relate - hints and references are both welcome.

So, first approach: say that I have a complex vector bundle $E\to M$; I can pass to the frame bundle $F(E)\to M$, where I have a $U(n)-$action, for some $n$. Then I consider the Chern-Weil map
\begin{equation}
S({\frak u}(n)^*)^{U(n)}\to H^*_{U(n)}(F(E))\simeq H^*(M)
\end{equation}
and pick the image of the invariant polynomial $tr$, the trace. (up to some constant)

Second approach: I pick a connection $D:\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E\otimes TM)$, with $\Gamma(\cdot)$ representing the space of sections, and consider its curvature. Work locally on some $U$ and pick a section $s$ which generates the bundle: we get $D(s)=\theta(s)\cdot s$, with $\theta(s)$ a $1-$form, and apparently the first Chern class is proportional to $d\theta(s)$.

I am a bit confused: the very idea of connection seems to be absent from the first approach, so either there's a natural choice of connection, or I get the same result no matter which one I pick. Moreover, it would seem to me that also the choice of generator $s$ matters.

Honestly, I don't have much of a clue about where to start tackling the problem - the two things seem quite unrelated.

Comment: What is your definition of the Chern-Weil map in the first approach? The approach I know also involves a connection (although the classes do end up being independent of this choice).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The induced map on (equivariant) cohomology from f: F(E) \to {pt}. you then use H^*_U(n)(pt.) = the polynomials on the Lie algebra of U(n) invariant under the adjoint action, and get the Chern-Weil map

Comment: Sure. Then yes, the point is that the Chern classes end up being independent of the choice of connection in the second approach.

Comment: that's good to know. but how does one show, from the first approach, that the image of the trace is a the curvature of a connection? btw, does this mean that in this case all the connections have the same curvature? nice! As I said, I'm a bit confused because the very idea of connection seems to be absent from the first approach

Comment: @nelv: It does not mean that all the connections have the same curvature, but rather that the _cohomology class_ of the curvature is the same for all connections.

Comment: I always think that the most easiest way to prove that two definitions of characteristic classes agree is to show that they both satisfy the axioms for characteristic classes and then be done.